# composable class instead of functions

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am new in jetpack compose,
is it good practice to use class instead of function in jetpack compose?

```
class Component{
   fun doSomeThing(){

   }
   @Composable
   fun render(){ 
     Text("Hello")
   }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun Component(
   doSomething:() -> Unit
){

   Text("Hello")
 
}
```

Comment: Google's conventions are that composables are pure functions, not member functions of a class. Some developers have experimented with having composable member functions, though.

Comment: I usually jump between classes using shortcuts. Declaring functions is simpler, but we should be careful to not end up with arbitrary file names containing a lot of composables not much related. I wonder why not classes.